# Find the volume of a tetrahedron

Tags: analytic-geometry

Let

$A(2,1,3), B(3,2,5), C(3,3,6), D(4,4,2)$

Find the volume $V$ of tetrahedron $ABCD$.

My Solution:

$\vec{AB} = (1, 1, 2), \vec{AC} = (1, 2, 3), \vec{AD} = (2, 3, -1)$

$$V=\begin{vmatrix}1&1&2\\1&2&3\\2&3&-1 \end{vmatrix}=-6$$

My question is: Is my solution right and can the volume be a negative number ?

Answer (score 2):

Note that the volume of a Tetrahedron = volume of a Pyramid with triangular base = 
$$= 1/3\,\text{ * }\,\text{base}\,\text{area}\,\text{ * }\,\text{height}$$
Then, if $\vec a,\,\vec b,\,\vec c$ are the vectors corresponding to three concurrent sides, the above is obtained as
$$
V = 1/3\left| {\left( {1/2\,\vec b \times \,\vec a} \right) \cdot \vec c} \right| = 1/6\left| {\;\left| {\begin{array}{*{20}c}
   {c_x } & {c_y } & {c_z }  \\
   {b_x } & {b_y } & {b_z }  \\
   {a_x } & {a_y } & {a_z }  \\
 \end{array} } \right|\;} \right|
$$
You shall take the absolute value, because $\vec b \times \,\vec a$
is a vector, whose orientation respect to $\vec c$ will determine a positive or negative
scalar result of the double product.

Answer (score 1):

The volume of a 3D parallelepiped with sides AB, AC and AD is given by

$$\left|\det(AB, AC, AD)\right|.$$

The parallelepiped is always $6$ times as voluminous as the corresponding tetrahedron $ABCD$, so the volume of the tetrahedron $ABCD$ is given by

$$\frac{1}{6}\left|\det(AB, AC, AD)\right|.$$

In this case, this means that the tetrahedron has a volume of exactly $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If you did this using $B$ as the origin point (using $BA, BC, BD$ in that order)
you would find 
$$
V=\frac16 \left| \pmatrix{-1&-1&-2\\0&1&1\\1&2&-3} \right| = \frac16 \cdot 6
$$
The determinant is equal to the volume only up to a factor of $\pm 1$; you can see this because if you change the order of any two of the sides, the determinant changes sign.

BTW, the $\frac16$ comes from $V = \frac13 Bh$ where $B$ is the area of the base, which is $\frac12 \ell w$.